# How to plug in an arbitrary view dynamically into xaml in MVVM application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are multiple places in my application whehe I have `ContentControl` placed in xaml and I do not know beforehand what its `Content` is going to be. What is the best practice to implement this scenario?

Right now I am considering two approaches:

1. Bind `ContentControl.Content` to view model and use a dictionary of `DataTemplate`s to find an appropriate view. My issue with this approach is that even if I were to list all the possible combinations in a dicitonary, in some cases I simply do not know an exact type of view (or viewmodel if there is any) at compilation time. I think, I am also going to have troubles using this approach for hosting non-WPF content.
2. Create some sort of an interface:

   ```
   interface IContentPlugin : IDisposable
   {
       object View { get; }
   }
   ```

   and bind `ContentControl.Content` to `IContentPlugin.View` directly. I could then have multiple implementations of this interface and swap them when I need to. But this solution does not strike me as something that goes well with MVVM application, as it forces me to have references to `IContentPlugin`s in my view models.

What do you think is the best option ***and why***? Perhaps there is a better approach?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204614/load-wpf-ui-into-mvvm-application-from-plug-in-assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I went with second approach. I was able to solve my main problem, which was:

> But this solution does not strike me as something that goes well with MVVM application, as it forces me to have references to IContentPlugins in my view models.

Passing those "plugins" into viewmodels was a mistake, you should not do it. What you can and should do is find a way to partition your view into smaller independent segments, and set their content in non-MVVM way. So basically I ended up with a view, which acted as container and looked like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name=this>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefiniton>
            <RowDefiniton>
            <RowDefiniton>
        </Grid.RowDefinition>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding PluginA.View, ElementName=this}"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding PluginB.View, ElementName=this}"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding PluginC.View, ElementName=this}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

where `PluginA`, `PluginB` and `PluginC` are dependency properties in code-behind, that are set by DI container using property injection. I am happy with the end-result, and it gives me the flexibility I need.

You can also use [PRISM](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), which roughly speaking does the same thing, but in more general and flexible manner. It was somewhat too complex for my application though, so I decided to keep it simple. But you should give it a try, if you are trying to solve similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

**You should use implicit View determination via DataTemplates.**

This is achieved by having type-specific `DataTemplates` (i.e. DataTemplates without a key reference) for your `ViewModel` types in a `ResourceDictionary` local to the scope of the `ContentControl`.

Be aware though that you will need to scope the `ResourceDictionary` quite carefully in the case where a single `ViewModel` can have multiple `Views` associated with it.

**Update**:

The reasons to use implicit `View` determination are:

- In general, the `View` resolution look-ups are faster than if you were to write a View resolving service.
- You're not duplicating effort by writing your own `View` resolver which you then need to plug into the `WPF` runtime.

You should be telling the external source what you support and in this case, keep it always to `WPF` `ResourceDictionary` so that regardless of the content/resources, you are able to merge it into your runtime `ResourceDictionaries` - this means,  your external sources will need to provide the `WinForms` control wrappers for you.

As someone who has created a plugin framework before using this pattern, working with a conceptually "pure MVVM" implementation simplifies things considerably - external sources supply a `ViewModel` class and a `ResourceDictionary` of the resources for the VM and you let `WPF` do the heavy-lifting of `View` determination for you.

Comment: Quoting myself: "My issue with this approach is that even if I were to list all the possible combinations in a dicitonary, in some cases I simply do not know an exact type of view (or viewmodel if there is any) at compilation time."

Comment: I know that, but how does it help? For example, some external source gives me `Winforms` control to host. How do I put that into `DataTemplate`? And why would I want to, what is the advantage of this approach? That's the question.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Sadly, I do not have control over those externals views. I get what I get. So I will probably have to create "fake" MVVM wrapper for every non-MVVM (or non-WPF) control I have to use, if I am to follow through with this approach. I'll need to think this over.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak you may be not able to define all possible views (combinations) at a point. But I think you can design your views derived from a base type or according to a contract. you must generalize your views to create some sort of definition for Templates.

Answer (score 2):

this is a very interesting scenario and for these cases I usually introduce a `ViewResolverService` or a `ViewModelResolverService` (or both). So something that can either give you the `ViewModel` based on a `view` (class,type or name) match them to host them in the `ContentControl`. Or a Service which can give you a view based on the ViewModel (type, or string name). With this powerful concept you can use ContentControls and/or DataTemplates and you have full control.

I answered some questions explaining the concepts here:

[Register all viewmodel and services in ViewModelLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651408/register-all-viewmodel-and-services-in-viewmodellocator/23652135#23652135)

and here:
[Get the View & ViewModel from a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384326/get-the-view-viewmodel-from-a-plugin/23385432#23385432)

more here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ViewModelResolver

So if you look at it from the birds eye view you need to apply MVVM to your ContentControls with your views. (And the views have also MVVM applied within themselves).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTemplate for ContentControls:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DataSourceViewModel}">
           <view:DataSourceView></view:DataSourceView>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SelectTemplateViewModel}">
           <view:SelectTemplateView></view:SelectTemplateView>
      </DataTemplate>
.........
........
    <ContentControl Margin="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" Name="ImportControls"></ContentControl>
```

**VM:is** the object type that is content of your contentcontrol

**View**: is specific view you want to see if object of a specific type is set as content of ContentControl

Comment: That's the first option he already considered. "What do you think is the best option **and why**?". Read the bold part ;)

Comment: He has already given a very good reason not to do second approach. Direct View reference in ViewModel layer.

Comment: hey @Tseng do you have answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311116/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-in-xaml-wpf  :)