# How to set Mouse Cursor in XAML / WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

**How can I set the Mouse cursor in XAML?**

What's the use of Cursor property in every control? Please don't answer as `Cursor="Arrow"` cause this is not working.

Only way I can do it right now is from code behind by
`Mouse.OverrideCursor`. Can I do it simply using XAML?

I have a Hierarchy of controls where there is a `GridSplitter` in between somewhere. I'm trying to set the Cursor to `SizeNS` but it's set to default as default `Arrow`. What Should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In WPF `Cursor` creates problem when controls are declared in hierarchy and properties get overwritten.

If you strictly want to set `Cursor` in a control use `ForceCursor` property of `FrameworkElement` class.

***Syntax:***

```
    <StackPanel Name="CursorForced" ForceCursor="true" Cursor="Hand">
        <Label>Cursors Forced</Label>
        <TextBox>Fill me in!</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

> ***In above example if I don't use `ForceCursor` the `Cursor` will be different over `TextBox` not as I defined in parent control.***

[MSDN link to How to Force Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.forcecursor(v=vs.110).aspx)